Set wsl2 to use host nameserver
I'm using wsl2 on Windows 11, and I recently encountered a problem where when I change networks, the wsl2 dns (nameserver at resolve.conf) address doesn't update, to match, and there for cannot lookup any domains.
I change the dns configuration often on my computer (work related) and I can't just set the nameserver to be 1.1.1.1 or something like that.
is there a way to tell the wsl to inherit the host (windows), and call upon it each time?

Enable mirror networking mode for WSL

For those who are looking an answer, though mirror networking is an option, since Windows 11 22H2 there is also the option to add in the .wslconfig file the following, specifically for DNS requests
[wsl2]
dnsTunneling=true

